# Mysql modify column not working

Tags: database, wordpress, ubuntu

What I wanna do is to update the field comment_author and change the type from tinytext to varchar(100)

For some reason it complains about **"Invaild default value for 'comment_date'"**

Why does it complain when I'm not even trying to change it? 
The command I'm using is:

```
 `mysql> Alter TABLE `wp_comments` MODIFY COLUMN `comment_author` VARCHAR(100);`
```

[image]

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about magento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strict mode affects whether the server permits '0000-00-00' as a valid date: If strict mode is not enabled, '0000-00-00' is permitted and inserts produce no warning. If strict mode is enabled, '0000-00-00' is not permitted and inserts produce an error, unless IGNORE is given as well. For INSERT IGNORE and UPDATE IGNORE, '0000-00-00' is permitted and inserts produce a warning.

reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36374335/error-in-mysql-when-setting-default-value-for-date-or-datetime